# Are there custom memory manager (mm) replacements for Linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, memory, virtual-memory

Are there alternatives to Linux kernel memory manager (`mm`)?

More specifically, are there companies that develop their own replacements for `mm` algorithms to suit specific needs such as supercomputing platforms, low-memory embedded systems, novel memory technologies, etc.?